# Problemas al recibir xml por peticion ajax jquery

Tags: php, ajax, xml

Estoy haciendo pruebas para un aplicacion. Quiero hacer una peticion ajax con jquery a un archivo php y recibir de la misma una estructura xml.

La peticion con Jquery la hago asi:

```
  $.post({
        url: 'php/procesar_xml.php',
        dataType: 'xml',
    })
    .done(respuesta)
    .fail(error);

function respuesta(datos) {
    console.log(datos);
}
```

Esa una peticion sencilla que no manda datos ni nada. Solo quiero recibir la estructura xml. El archivo php lo tengo definido asi:

```
  <?php
  header('Content-Type:text/xml');
  $xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>';
  $xml.='<TRABAJADOR>';
  $xml.='<ID_TRABAJADOR>123456</ID_TRABAJADOR>';
  $xml.='<NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR>juan</NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR>';
  $xml.='</TRABAJADOR>';
```

La peticion me devuelve el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Mensaje de error Error: Invalid XML: 
<?xml version="1.0"?><TRABAJADOR><ID_TRABAJADOR>123456</ID_TRABAJADOR><NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR>juan</NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR></TRABAJADOR>
```

He probado de varias maneras pero siempre me devuelve el mismo error.
¿A que se puede deber?
Un saludo.

Comment: Problema resuelto. El problema es que el documento php donde formaba el xml tenia un espacio puesto antes de abrir la etiqueta <?php y por eso me daba el error.

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que el [`XML`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Markup_Language) carece de **un elemento raíz**.

### Solución:

Debes agregar un elemento que contenga a todos los datos del trabajador.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:text/xml');

$xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>';
$xml.='<TRABAJADOR>';
$xml.='<ID_TRABAJADOR>123456</ID_TRABAJADOR>';
$xml.='<NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR>juan</NOMBRE_TRABAJADOR>';
$xml.='</TRABAJADOR>';
echo $xml;
```

Mas Info:

- [Documentos XML bien formados y control de errores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Markup_Language#Documentos_XML_bien_formados_y_control_de_errores)

Comment: Hola Marcos: He probado y me sigue dando el mismo error:

Comment: @CarlosRayonAlvarez, la verdad que no sabría decirte, ya que no puedo reproducir el error.